# Run cucumber and generate html report without maven/gradle plugins

Tags: java, cucumber, html-reports-jenkins

I am currently using cucumber and the masterthought plugin to generate html reports on test executions. I want to enable future flexibility to configure the cucumber options when running my tests from a gradle script as well as running the cucumber from java code without the need of using plugins on build script.

I have previously used the `surefire` plugin to run the cucumber and the `masterthought` plugin to generate the cucumber report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.my.domain;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions;
import cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Reportable;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
            "json:build/path/cucumber.json" }, 
        features = {
            "src/main/resources/features" }, 
        glue = {
            "com.my.domain.stepdefinitions" }, 
        dryRun = false, 
        tags = {"@tag"}

)
public class CucumberJunitRunner {
    // TODO: Make Tags, Features, Glue, plugin runtime, and path configurable
    private static final String JSON_PLUGIN_PREFIX = "json:";
    private static final String PRECONFIGURED_REPORT_OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "cucumber-html-reports";
    private static final Optional<String> REPORT_OUTPUT_FOLDER_LOCATION = Optional.ofNullable(null);
    private static final boolean SKIP_REPORT_GENERATION = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InitializationError {
        RuntimeOptions cucumberRuntimeOptions = null;
        Optional<String> jsonPluginOutputLocation = Optional.empty();
        if(args.length > 0) {
            //TODO: USE ARGUMENTS TO INITIALIZE cucumberRuntimeOptions AND jsonPluginOutputLocation
        } else {
            RuntimeOptionsFactory cucumberRuntimeOptionsFactory = new RuntimeOptionsFactory(CucumberJunitRunner.class);
            cucumberRuntimeOptions = cucumberRuntimeOptionsFactory.create();

            jsonPluginOutputLocation = cucumberRuntimeOptions.getPluginFormatterNames().stream()
                    .filter(s -> s.startsWith(JSON_PLUGIN_PREFIX))
                    .map(s -> s.substring(JSON_PLUGIN_PREFIX.length())).findFirst();
            if( ! jsonPluginOutputLocation.isPresent() ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                        "Could not find jsonPluginOutputLocation in plugins from cucumber options: %s",
                        cucumberRuntimeOptions.getPluginFormatterNames()));
            }
        }

        deletePreviousData(jsonPluginOutputLocation);
        runCucumber(cucumberRuntimeOptions, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        if (SKIP_REPORT_GENERATION) {
            System.out.println("Report generation skipped. No HTML report was built.");
        } else {
            if (cucumberRuntimeOptions.isDryRun()) {
                System.out.println("Cucumber DryRun executed. No HTML report was built.");
            } else {
                if (jsonPluginOutputLocation.isPresent()) {
                    Path jsonPluginOutputPath = Paths.get(jsonPluginOutputLocation.get());
                    if (Files.exists(jsonPluginOutputPath)) {
                        generateCucumberReport(
                                REPORT_OUTPUT_FOLDER_LOCATION.orElse(
                                        FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(jsonPluginOutputLocation.get())),
                                jsonPluginOutputLocation.get(), "1", "My Project");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Cucumber JSON report was missing. No HTML report was built.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cucumber JSON plugin was missing. No HTML report was built.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void deletePreviousData(Optional<String> jsonPluginOutputLocation) {
        Path jsonPluginOutputPath = Paths.get(jsonPluginOutputLocation.get());
        if (Files.exists(jsonPluginOutputPath)) {
            try {
                Files.delete(jsonPluginOutputPath);
                System.out.println("Cucumber JSON file was deleted: " +
                        jsonPluginOutputPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cucumber JSON file from previous execution was not detected: "
                    + jsonPluginOutputPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        }

        Path cucumberReportsFolder = jsonPluginOutputPath.resolveSibling(PRECONFIGURED_REPORT_OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);
        if (Files.exists(cucumberReportsFolder)) {
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(cucumberReportsFolder.toFile());
                System.out.println("Cucumber JSON report was deleted: " + 
                        cucumberReportsFolder.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cucumber JSON report from previous execution was not detected: "
                    + cucumberReportsFolder.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Launches the Cucumber-JVM command line.
     *
     * @param argv        runtime options. See details in the
     *                    {@code cucumber.api.cli.Usage.txt} resource.
     * @param classLoader classloader used to load the runtime
     * @return 0 if execution was successful, 1 if it was not (test failures)
     */
    public static byte runCucumber(RuntimeOptions cucumberRuntimeOptions, ClassLoader classLoader) {

        final cucumber.runtime.Runtime runtime = cucumber.runtime.Runtime.builder()
                .withRuntimeOptions(cucumberRuntimeOptions).withClassLoader(classLoader).build();

        runtime.run();

        return runtime.exitStatus();
    }

    private static void generateCucumberReport(String reportOutputDirectoryLocation, String cucumberJsonFile,
            String buildNumber, String projectName) {

        File reportOutputDirectory = new File(reportOutputDirectoryLocation);
        List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        jsonFiles.add(cucumberJsonFile);
        // jsonFiles.add("cucumber-report-2.json");

        // String buildNumber = "1";
        // String projectName = "cucumberProject";
        boolean runWithJenkins = false;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
        // optional configuration - check javadoc
        configuration.setRunWithJenkins(runWithJenkins);
        configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);
        // addidtional metadata presented on main page
        // configuration.addClassifications("Platform", "Windows");
        // configuration.addClassifications("Browser", "Firefox");
        // configuration.addClassifications("Branch", "release/1.0");

        // optionally add metadata presented on main page via properties file
        //List<String> classificationFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        //classificationFiles.add("properties-1.properties");
        //classificationFiles.add("properties-2.properties");
        // configuration.addClassificationFiles(classificationFiles);

        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
        Reportable result = reportBuilder.generateReports();
        // and here validate 'result' to decide what to do if report has failed

        if (result == null) {
            System.out.println("There was an isssue while building the report");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```